# Numpy Root-Mean-Squared (RMS) smoothing of a signal

Tags: numpy, iteration, scipy, smoothing, moving-average

I have a signal of electromyographical data that I am supposed (scientific papers' explicit recommendation) to smooth using RMS.

I have the following working code, producing the desired output, but it is way slower than I think it's possible.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy
def rms(interval, halfwindow):
    """ performs the moving-window smoothing of a signal using RMS """
    n = len(interval)
    rms_signal = numpy.zeros(n)
    for i in range(n):
        small_index = max(0, i - halfwindow)  # intended to avoid boundary effect
        big_index = min(n, i + halfwindow)    # intended to avoid boundary effect
        window_samples = interval[small_index:big_index]

        # here is the RMS of the window, being attributed to rms_signal 'i'th sample:
        rms_signal[i] = sqrt(sum([s**2 for s in window_samples])/len(window_samples))

    return rms_signal
```

I have seen some `deque` and `itertools` suggestions regarding optimization of moving window loops, and also `convolve` from numpy, but I couldn't figure it out how to accomplish what I want using them.

Also, I do not care to avoid boundary problems anymore, because I end up having large arrays and relatively small sliding windows.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Can you link to the paper? I've never heard of smoothing a signal by computing the RMS of the points over a moving window. In general, this will not look like a smoothed version of the original signal.

Comment: Smoothing this way is suggested because it correlates with signal power (energy), and this could be used to infer muscle effort. Link: http://www.isek-online.org/standards_emg.html "Another acceptable method of providing amplitude information is the "Root Mean Square" or RMS. Just as the moving average, this quantity is defined for a specific time interval (moving window) T which must be indicated." It is the first choice for smoothing according to Noraxon booklet (closed source, owned by my company) with a time window between 50 and 100ms more or less.

Comment: RMS of a moving window is the idea behind audio level meters, too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It **is** possible to use convolution to perform the operation you are referring to. I did it a few times for processing EEG signals as well.

```py
import numpy as np
def window_rms(a, window_size):
  a2 = np.power(a,2)
  window = np.ones(window_size)/float(window_size)
  return np.sqrt(np.convolve(a2, window, 'valid'))
```

Breaking it down, the `np.power(a, 2)` part makes a new array with the same dimension as `a`, but where each value is squared. `np.ones(window_size)/float(window_size)` produces an array or length `window_size` where each element is `1/window_size`. So the convolution effectively produces a new array where each element `i` is equal to

```
(a[i]^2 + a[i+1]^2 + … + a[i+window_size]^2)/window_size
```

which is the RMS value of the array elements within the moving window. It should perform really well this way.

Note, though, that `np.power(a, 2)` produces a **new** array of same dimension. If `a` is **really** large, I mean sufficiently large that it cannot fit twice in memory, you might need a strategy where each element are modified in place. Also, the `'valid'` argument specifies to discard border effects, resulting in a smaller array produced by `np.convolve()`. You could keep it all by specifying `'same'` instead (see [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)).

Comment: Great, great, great, very clever! EMG signals are way shorter than EMG, less than 50mb for 4 channel recording, so memory usage won't be prohibitive. And I plan to use `'same'`, for display in stack with raw/smoothed/filtered signal.

Comment: Just for the record, RMS now is 500 times faster (0.002 vs 1.000 s for `window_size' of 16 samples as measured by `cProfile'), and does not get much slower for way larger (100+) windows. Did I say it's great?

Comment: You should never specify anything other than 'valid' using the code you have since the second argument to `np.convolve()` contains the inverse of the full window length.

Comment: Just to extend this a bit, it is possible to have `window` be a kernel whose sum is `1.0`, like normalized gaussian kernel, if some more esoteric behaviour is needed. Actually, the three lines of code in the function perform what some DSP texts generically call "delinearization", "demodulation" and "relinearization", which can be done with different power (besides two), kernel (besides unitary square or gaussian), statistical operator (besides weighted average) and window size.

Comment: Should `np.convolve(a2, window, 'valid')` be replaced for `np.convolve(a2, window_size, 'valid')` ? Looks like a typo in the `window` for `np.convolve`

Answer (score 1):

I found my machine struggling with convolve, so I propose the following solution:

**Compute Moving RMS Window Quickly**

Suppose we have analog voltage samples a0 ... a99 (one hundred samples) and we need to take moving RMS of 10 samples through them.

The window will scan initially from elements a0 to a9 (ten samples) to get rms0.

```
    # rms = [rms0, rms1, ... rms99-9] (total of 91 elements in list):
    (rms0)^2 = (1/10) (a0^2 + ...         + a9^2)            # --- (note 1)
    (rms1)^2 = (1/10) (...    a1^2 + ...  + a9^2 + a10^2)    # window moved a step, a0 falls out, a10 comes in
    (rms2)^2 = (1/10) (              a2^2 + ... + a10^2 + a11^2)     # window moved another step, a1 falls out, a11 comes in
    ...
```

Simplifying it: We have`a = [a0, ... a99]`
To create moving RMS of 10 samples, we can take sqrt of the addition of 10 `a^2`'s and multiplied by 1/10.

In other words, if we have

```
    p = (1/10) * a^2 = 1/10 * [a0^2, ... a99^2]
```

To get `rms^2` simply add a group of 10 p's.

Let's have an acummulator acu:

```
    acu = p0 + ... p8     # (as in note 1 above)
```

Then we can have

```
    rms0^2 =  p0 + ...  p8 + p9 
           = acu + p9
    rms1^2 = acu + p9 + p10 - p0
    rms2^2 = acu + p9 + p10 + p11 - p0 - p1
    ...
```

we can create (look at vertical column in the addition below):

```
    V0 = [acu,   0,   0, ...  0]
    V1 = [ p9, p10, p11, .... p99]          -- len=91
    V2 = [  0, -p0, -p1, ... -p89]          -- len=91

    V3 = V0 + V1 + V2
```

if we run
`itertools.accumulate(V3)`
we will get rms array

Code:

```py
    import numpy as np
    from   itertools import accumulate

    a2 = np.power(in_ch, 2) / tm_w                  # create array of p, in_ch is samples, tm_w is window length
    v1 = np.array(a2[tm_w - 1 : ])                  # v1 = [p9, p10, ...]
    v2 = np.append([0], a2[0 : len(a2) - tm_w])     # v2 = [0,   p0, ...]
    acu = list(accumulate(a2[0 : tm_w - 1]))        # get initial accumulation (acu) of the window - 1
    v1[0] = v1[0] + acu[-1]                         # rms element #1 will be at end of window and contains the accumulation
    rmspw2 = list(accumulate(v1 - v2))
    
    rms = np.power(rmspw2, 0.5)
```

I can compute an array of 128 Mega samples in less than 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not a linear transformation, I don't believe it is possible to use np.convolve().

Here's a function which should do what you want. Note that the first element of the returned array is the rms of the first full window; i.e. for the array `a` in the example, the return array is the rms of the subwindows `[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]` and does not include the partial windows `[1]` and `[5]`.

```
>>> def window_rms(a, window_size=2):
>>>     return np.sqrt(sum([a[window_size-i-1:len(a)-i]**2 for i in range(window_size-1)])/window_size)
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> window_rms(a)
array([ 1.41421356,  2.44948974,  3.46410162,  4.47213595])
```

Comment: It **is** possible to use convolution, see my answer.