# audioop.rms() - why does it differ from normal RMS?

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a python function to return the loudness of a .wav file. RMS seems to be best the metric for this, [Detect and record a sound with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668442/detect-and-record-a-sound-with-python). 
`audioop.rms()` does the trick, but I'd like to avoid audioop as a dependency, and I already import numpy. but I'm not getting the same RMS values, and would appreciate help in understanding what is going on.

From the [audioop page](http://docs.python.org/library/audioop.html), it says that the rms calculation is just what you'd expect, namely `sqrt(sum(S_i^2)/n)`, where, `S_i` is the `i`-th sample of the sound. Seems like its not rocket science.

To use numpy, I first convert the sound to a numpy array, and always see identical min / max, and the same length of the data (so the conversion seems fine).

```
>>> d = np.frombuffer(data, np.int16)
>>> print (min(d), max(d)), audioop.minmax(data,2)
(-2593, 2749) (-2593, 2749)
```

but I get very different RMS values, not even ball-park close:

```
>>> numpy_rms = np.sqrt(sum(d*d)/len(d))
>>> print numpy_rms, audioop.rms(data, 2)
41.708703254716383, 120
```

The difference between them is variable, no obvious pattern I can see, eg, I also get:

```
63.786714248938772, 402
62.779300661773405, 148
```

My numpy RMS code gives identical output to the one here: [Numpy Root-Mean-Squared (RMS) smoothing of a signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245687/numpy-root-mean-squared-rms-smoothing-of-a-signal)

I don't see where I am going wrong, but something is off. Any help much appreciated.

---

EDITED / UPDATE:

In case its useful, here's the code I ended up with. Its not quite as fast as audioop but is still plenty fast, good enough for my purpose. Of note, using np.mean() makes it MUCH faster (~100x) than my version using python sum().

```
def np_audioop_rms(data, width):
    """audioop.rms() using numpy; avoids another dependency for app"""
    #_checkParameters(data, width)
    if len(data) == 0: return None
    fromType = (np.int8, np.int16, np.int32)[width//2]
    d = np.frombuffer(data, fromType).astype(np.float)
    rms = np.sqrt( np.mean(d**2) )
    return int( rms )
```

Comment: thanks but no go. using: "d = np.frombuffer(data, np.short)" gives exactly the same behavior.

Comment: sorry, I've deleted the comment before I saw the reply. btw, you could use [`window_rms()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245687/numpy-root-mean-squared-rms-smoothing-of-a-signal) if you use `double` to calculate `np.power(a, 2)` e.g., by changing it to `np.power(a, 2.)`.

Comment: why can't you use `audioop`? How large is the data? Can you use a C extension?

Comment: I could use audioop, but doing so would mean packaging another dependency for the application (= larger download, and more hassle when building the release). we already include numpy, and don't need every last microsecond. probably only short sound clips.

Comment: audioop is in stdlib or am i missing something? you could use `np.power(np.frombuffer(data, dtype=fromType), 2.0).mean()**.5` to avoid making a copy with `.astype()` (here `power` creates float array).

Comment: I thought it was in stdlib too, but get an import error (when using the version of python we package, 2.6.6, as packaged).

Comment: dumb question, how do you get the data width where data = u.read(8192)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perform calculations using `double` as in [`audioop.rms()` code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/audioop.c#l410):

```
d = np.frombuffer(data, np.int16).astype(np.float)
```

#### Example

```
>>> import audioop, numpy as np
>>> data = 'abcdefgh'
>>> audioop.rms(data, 2)
25962
>>> d = np.frombuffer(data, np.int16)
>>> np.sqrt((d*d).sum()/(1.*len(d)))
80.131142510262507
>>> d = np.frombuffer(data, np.int16).astype(np.float)
>>> np.sqrt((d*d).sum()/len(d))
25962.360851817772
```

Comment: thanks! perfect. I voted 'up' but don't have 15 reputation points yet.

Answer (score 0):

From matplotlib.mlab:

```
def rms_flat(a):
    """
    Return the root mean square of all the elements of *a*, flattened out.
    """
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.absolute(a)**2))
```

Comment: nice. for me, the conversion to np.float prior to rms was the issue.