# How to get rms from a audio wav file using python?

Tags: python, audio, wav, rms

How can I use width 2 to get result without error?

The width is 2, but I will get error.

If I change it to 1, I can get a result from the code but its incorrect.

```
import wave
import contextlib
import audioop

fname = "some.wav"

with contextlib.closing(wave.open(fname,'r')) as f:

    frames = f.getnframes()
    rate = f.getframerate()
    duration = frames / float(rate)
    width = f.getsampwidth()
    channel = f.getnchannels()
    size = width*channel
    # f.rewind()
    wav = f.readframes(f.getnframes())
    # print(duration)

print(audioop.rms(str(wav).encode("ascii"),2))
```

> "audioop.error: not a whole number of frames"

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Python so let me know if one of these possible option fixes it...

Option 1:

According to [Audioop docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/audioop.html):

> *"It operates on sound fragments consisting of signed integer samples 8, 16 or 32 bits wide."*

Consider the following:

- `f.getsampwidth()` gives width in bytes length, so you have **2 bytes**.
- 1 byte contains 8-bits, so 2 bytes will be **16-bits** wide.

Try as:

```
print(audioop.rms(str(wav).encode("ascii"),16))
```

Option 2:

> *"If I change it to `1`, I can get a result from the code but it's incorrect."*

Maybe the original line: `print(audioop.rms(str(wav).encode("ascii"),2))` is correct and the real issue is `not enough bytes` to divide by 2 (of width).

Make sure the WAV'a audio format really is 16-bit and/or Stereo.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but I came across an answer on another question: 
[audioop.rms() - why does it differ from normal RMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763471/audioop-rms-why-does-it-differ-from-normal-rms)

Maybe try using:

```
audioop.rms(wav, 2)
```

Where the 2 represents the number of bytes (in this case int16)